# CSS DropDown Menu Not Aligned Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, wordpress-theming

I developed http://pizzli.com/millington for a client and used just CSS for the dropdown menus. They came out good, however the are aligned to the right for some reason. Take a look at the picture below. Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: the submenu is actually aligned to the center, just test changing your text-align:left and you will see, your rules are messed up I recommend you making your own rules for submenu, it's beacuse of the parent element padding your center moves

Answer (score 0):

hey i thing you want your dropdown navi is started left than you give to your li position relative and sub ul give to left and absolute properties as like this

**Some change to your css file**

```
#navigation li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
}
```

and this

```
#navigation li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: -16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try making the `left: inherit;` and then doing `margin-left: xyz;` to position the elements relative to the parent. 
Note you might have to change the `left:` and `margin-left:` to `right:` and `margin-right:`, but this worked great for me, and I spent quite a long time figuring it out.